# NestJS : cannot provide an instance to child module owning the interface

Tags: nestjs, clean-architecture

I try to decouple the controller module of a NestJs module from a domain module (as per clean architecture principles), so that dependency flows only to Domain.
I do not understand how to make it work, injection of the repo interface's implementation does not happen (error when nest starts).

Here is the module structure :

```
AppModule     ->     CommunityControllerModule     ->     DomainModule
                       (provides repoImpl                   (has service requiring an unknown
                        by token)                            concrete repo interface impl)
```

The CommunityControllerModule :

```
import { DomainModule } from 'libs/domain/src';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommunityController } from './community.controller';
import { CommunityRepositoryImpl } from './community.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [DomainModule, CommunityRepositoryImpl],
  controllers: [CommunityController],
  exports: [CommunityRepositoryImpl],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'CommunityRepository',
      useClass: CommunityRepositoryImpl,
    },
  ],
})
export class CommunityControllerModule {}
```

The DomainModule :

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommunityService } from './community.service';

@Module({
  providers: [CommunityService],
  exports: [CommunityService],
})
export class DomainModule {}
```

The CommunityService where injection fails :

```
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommunityRepository } from './community.repo';

@Injectable()
export class CommunityService {
  
  constructor(
    @Inject('CommunityRepository') private repo: CommunityRepository,
  ) {}
}
```

The outputted error :

```
> nest start

webpack 5.28.0 compiled successfully in 8218 ms
[Nest] 7204   - 2021-05-05 20:52:05   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 7204   - 2021-05-05 20:52:05   [InstanceLoader] CommunityRepositoryImpl dependencies initialized +49ms
[Nest] 7204   - 2021-05-05 20:52:05   [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CommunityService (?). Please make sure that the argument CommunityRepository at index [0] is available in the DomainModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If CommunityRepository is a provider, is it part of the current DomainModule?
- If CommunityRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within DomainModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing CommunityRepository */ ]
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I missed was to set the DomainModule as a [dynamic module](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules).

The Domain module becomes :

```
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommunityService } from './community.service';

@Module({})
export class DomainModule {
  static register(repoImpl): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: DomainModule,
      imports: [repoImpl],
      providers: [
        CommunityService,
        {
          provide: 'CommunityRepository',
          useClass: repoImpl,
        },
      ],
      exports: [CommunityService],
    };
  }
}
```

...and the CommunityControllerModule imports it with the repo implementation :

```
import { DomainModule } from 'libs/domain/src';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CommunityController } from './community.controller';
import { CommunityRepositoryImpl } from './community.repository';

@Module({
  imports: [
    DomainModule.register(CommunityRepositoryImpl),
    CommunityRepositoryImpl,
  ],
  controllers: [CommunityController],
  exports: [CommunityRepositoryImpl],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'CommunityRepository',
      useClass: CommunityRepositoryImpl,
    },
  ],
})
export class CommunityControllerModule {}
```